# Optimized way of Querying in MongoDB using $in vs $or

Tags: mongodb

Implementing an application that looks up a table for mail id presence from a list of around 10 email ids. Tried using $or and $in.

$in seems to give better performance but not significant. Is one more optimized than other?

Comment: Well for starters an $in only take one index, that is significant due to the reason why an $or takes more (one per clause). An $or is like getting the result for each clause and then merging duplicates and returning a result. So that is one major point to consider here, whereas $in is a range identifier. By laws of computer science I would say that if you can use $in it would be more optimised than $or

Answer (score 33, accepted):

MongoDB docs have [the answer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/#_S_or%22):

"When using $or with <expressions> that are equality checks for the value of the same field, choose the $in operator over the $or operator."

Comment: Good answer, But why does `docs` prefer `$in` for equality checks?

Comment: some day it may not make a difference, currently the query optimizer chooses a *slightly* different plan between the two and while when that's the only predicate it doesn't make a difference performance-wise, when there are other predicates involved, it *may* make a difference.   Plus writing it as $in make it significantly easier to read - it's immediately obvious that the same field is being tested against multiple values.

Answer (score 8):

`$or` operator is logical operator where you can define your own login but `$in` operator is **Comparison operator** where you can compare you can not put your on logic.

Syntax of `$in`:

```
{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }
```

Example:

```
db.account.find( { qty: { $in: [ 5, 15 ] } } )
```

Syntax of `$or`:

```
{ $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

Example:

```
db.account.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] } )
```

Note: Account is your collection name

Answer (score 5):

"While  "$or"will always work, use  "$in"whenever possible as the query optimizer
handles it more efficiently."

Moreover "$in" has more readability.

Ref: MongoDB: The Definitive Guide

Answer (score 0):

Well that will insure no indecis to be ensured if you use $in, however i prefer to format it to $or as it will ensure index (readability won't concern me at is being handled in application logic in which i prefer to consume the memory of app rather than mongodb server)

Comment: $in absolutely takes advantage of indexes. You can test this easily by using .explain() https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/