# Convert SQL query to MongoDB aggregation where something="this" or something = "that"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Query:

```
Select * from table1 where f1 = "val1" OR f1 = "val2"
```

I need to convert this query to MongoDB query but using aggregation not find.

Comment: are you using sequelize?

Comment: No, I am using mongoDB with RoR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need the aggregation framework for this, a simple **`find()`** query with the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** or **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or)** operator will do just fine:

```
db.collection.find({
    "f1": { "$in": ["val1", "val2"] }
})
```

Using the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or)** operator:

```
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [
        { "f1": "val1" },
        { "f1": "val2" }
    ]
})
```

which is just syntantic sugar for the above **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)**

---

For an aggregation pipeline approach, you can run the following pipeline which uses the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator to query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "f1": { "$in": ["val1", "val2"] } } }
])
```

or with the $or operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
           "$or": [
               { "f1": "val1" }, 
               { "f1": "val2" }
           ] 
        } 
    } 
])
```

---

From the docs **[`$or` vs `$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in)**, it's recommended

> When using **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or)** with `<expressions>` that are equality checks for the
>   value of the same field, use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator instead of the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or)**
>   operator.

Comment: which is faster? in or or ?

Comment: Refer to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736656/optimized-way-of-querying-in-mongodb-using-in-vs-or

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and `$in` or `$or`
Your query could look like this

```
db.table1.aggregate( [
  { $match: { f1: { $in: ['val1', 'val2'] } } }
] );
```